iOS Widget Image not displaying when OS18 Tint mode is enabled
I'm implementing an iOS widget. An image is retrieved from photos, and displayed in the Widget along with a few basic functional buttons (not included here).
The widget works fine building locally or from TestFlight when the device display preference is normal on all devices over various OS versions.
However, on iOS 18, there's a "Tint" feature which allows tinting of your springboard icons and widgets. When this mode is enabled, the image will not display.
I have tried converting to JPG, PNG and TIFF. I've tried converting to monochrome and black and white. I've tried reducing sizes down to very small.
In each case, the converted image displays properly in normal mode, but it will not display with Tint enabled.
The image frame appears, but the OS is essentially overlaying the entire image itself with the Tint color.
Below is the code for the most simplistic Widget layout to show an image. Nothing special is going on. The image simply will not display.
It's been a long time since I've had to reach out to the experts on this great site for advise, but this absolutely merits the question.
This is how the image displays with tint enabled.

struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent(), screenshot: nil)
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> SimpleEntry {
        let screenshot = PhotosManager.shared.loadMostRecentScreenshotThumb()
        return SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, screenshot: screenshot)
    }

    func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
        let screenshot = PhotosManager.shared.loadMostRecentScreenshotThumb()
        let currentDate = Date()
        let nextRefreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: currentDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: currentDate, configuration: configuration, screenshot: screenshot)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(nextRefreshDate))
        return timeline
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent
    let screenshot: UIImage?
}

struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let screenshot = entry.screenshot {
                Image(uiImage: screenshot)
                    .widgetAccentable()
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding(5)
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}

struct DS_Widget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Shot_Widget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .containerBackground(Color.clear, for: .widget)
        }
        .contentMarginsDisabled()
    }
}

And here is the code to retrieve the photo from photos.
func loadMostRecentScreenshotThumb() -> UIImage? {
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: getOptions())
    if let asset = result.firstObject {
        let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .fastFormat

        var image: UIImage?
        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions) { result, _ in
            image = result
        }
        return image
    }
    return nil
}

ADDED NOTE: What's even worse, is while I was composing this, I changed the size of the image I was retrieving from photos to request 100x100 directly and the image appeared and it WAS TINTED! Thinking I just solved it, I changed it to 120x120 to test and the image is gone again and will not display. That's the first time I've seen the image displayed while Tint mode was enabled.
This is a very interesting and frustrating issue. Any help would be great and thank you!

You should not use .widgetAccentable() in this case. .widgetAccentable() turns all the non-transparent regions of your image to the home screen tint color.
If you want to display the image without modifying its color, even in a tinted environment, you should use,
Image(uiImage: screenshot)
    .widgetAccentedRenderingMode(.fullColor)

If you want to respect the user's choice of tint color to some degree, pass in .accentedDesaturated instead of .fullColor.
An image like this:

will be displayed like this if I choose a reddish color as tint:

